# Difference between hazelcast.jar and hazelcast-all.jar

Tags: java, hazelcast

Current release of Hazelcast is 3.4 and I see there are two jars in the lib folder of the download page http://hazelcast.org/download/

- hazelcast-3.4.jar
- hazelcast-all-3.4.jar

What is the diffence between these jars? WHcih one should I choose, and why?

Comment: Did you open the jars and check if there is any difference in the contents? Some libraries have jars containing only the bare minumum interfaces/abstract classes to allow your code to compile. A classic example for this is the servlet-api.jar

Comment: I opened them but there are bunch of files. I think it would be waste of time to check all the class files. I actually wanted to figure out why to use one not the other. How can I understand that hazelcast.jar is enough and not hazlecast-all.jar is not necessary and/or vice versa...

Answer (score 13):

hazelcast–3.4.1.jar — The core hazelcast JAR.

hazelcast-all–3.4.1.jar — Includes all of the libraries here in one JAR file.

hazelcast-client–3.4.1.jar — Java native client library to be included on classpath for Hazelcast client.

hazelcast-cloud–3.4.1.jar — To connect to a Hazelcast cluster on AWS as a client or node, include this library.

hazelcast-hibernate(Hibernate version)–3.4.1.jar — These are the libraries that enable Hazelcast to be used as a Hibernate 2nd Level Cache, for Hibernate 3 and 4.

hazelcast-jca–3.4.1.jar and hazelcast-jca-rar–3.4.1.rar — These are the libraries when you want to use a Hazelcast Resource Adapter implementation.

hazelcast-spring–3.4.1.jar — This is the library to integrate Hazelcast with Spring based applications.

hazelcast-wm–3.4.1.jar — This is the Hazelcast's session replication module library.

Comment: I understand there is difference of "all" and others between these files but -sorry- this is not the answer to my question. How do you choose the jar? Why would I choose the core and why would I choose all.jar?

Comment: lets say, you want to use server and client at the same time. You can add hazelcast-all.jar directly to your classpath. Or you can add hazelcast.jar and hazelcast-client.jar seperately.

Comment: Another case: lets say you want use only server, so you can add hazelcast.jar to your classpath. Actually if you care about size of your application you can use separate jars but if you don't care about size of your application only use hazelcast-all.jar

Comment: shortly hazelcast-all includes all jars. hazelcast.jar includes only server side. It is enough to use hazelcast only adding hazelcast.jar to your classpath. This is minimum.

Comment: Thank you for clarifications. Starting with version 4 the client does not exist and is included in the core `hazelcast-4.1.3.jar` - https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.1/migration-guides#removal-of-hazelcast-client-module